# convert array to json in typescript

Tags: arrays, json, typescript

i m trying to convert an array to json in typeScript, how can i do it to get this result please:

```
 let array=['element1', 'element2', 'element3']

result=[{"value"="element1"},{"value"="element2"}, {"value"="element3"}]
```

Comment: The result you want is invalid, both as JSON and as JavaScript.

Comment: You appear to be confused about the difference between JSON, which is a text format for sending and storing data, and objects, which are simply another structure in JavaScript. See [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2904131/215552).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be clear, the JSON version of your array would be exactly that:

```
['element1', 'element2', 'element3']
```

If you want to add the `value` field, you can manually add it first, before converting into JSON.

### Working demo

The below code produces this:

```
[{"value":"element1"},{"value":"element2"},{"value":"element3"}]
```

```js
let array = ['element1', 'element2', 'element3']

let arrayWithValue = array.map(el => ({value: el}));

console.log(JSON.stringify(arrayWithValue));
```